# Working With UTC Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, utc

In an ASP.Net web form, I am converting the current date and time to UTC format.

```
Dim ClickDT As String = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc.ToString
```

This value generated in VB.Net will be passed as a URL parameter to another web page that will process it using jQuery.

On the jQuery side, I want to have a date time range that give the user a 10 minute window. This is what I have been using, but how do I modify it so that it takes into account the UTC value that is passed?

```
var DateSent = decodeURIComponent(GetURLParameter('MyUTCDateValue'));
var PassedDT = new Date(DateSent);
var MinCurrentDT = new Date($.now());
var MaxCurrentDT = new Date($.now());

MinCurrentDT.setMinutes(MinCurrentDT.getMinutes() - 5);
MaxCurrentDT.setMinutes(MaxCurrentDT.getMinutes() + 5);

 if (PassedDT >= MinCurrentDT && PassedDT <= MaxCurrentDT) {
        alert('Date Time is good.');                         
    }
    else {
        alert('Date is outside range.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Local Time Zone's Offset to the MinCurrentDT and MinCurrentDT variables.

```
//Get offset in minutes:
var LocalOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

MinCurrentDT.setMinutes(MinCurrentDT.getMinutes() - 5 + LocalOffset);
MaxCurrentDT.setMinutes(MaxCurrentDT.getMinutes() + 5 + LocalOffset);
```

Comment: I also had to modify my vb.net code.  Dim ClickDT As String = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString